# spacebar not checking checkboxes, instead scrolling down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have checkboxes that I'm trying to check with spacebar. But when the input is focused, and I press on the spacebar, it just scrolls me down. Here's my sample checkbox code:

```css
.visually-hidden {
  position: absolute!important;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
}
```

```html
<li class="filter-item" tabindex="0">
  <label data-filter-item="" class="filter-item__content " for="filter--filter.p.product_type--Blouse--top-bar">
    <input type="checkbox" name="filter.p.product_type" value="Blouse" class="filter-item__checkbox visually-hidden" data-filter-item-input="" data-filter="filter.p.product_type=Blouse" data-value-escaped="Blouse" id="filter--filter.p.product_type--Blouse--top-bar">

    <div class="filter-item__content-inner"><div class="filter-input__input">
        <span class="icon icon-new icon-checkmark ">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m1.88 11.988 6.21 6.103L22.467 3.83" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="3.055"></path></svg>
        </span>
        
        </div><span class="filter-item__label">
          Blouse
        </span>
        <span class="filter-item__count fs-body-75">(19)</span></div>
  </label>
</li>
```

I've tried adding this to my filtering function, I get the console log when I press spacebar on a checkbox, but it still scrolls me down:

```
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    if (e.key === ' ') {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('spacebar is pressed');
  }
  });
```

Please help me out. I have tried a lot of things and it doesn't seem to change.

Comment: The problem is likely that a div isn't keyboard-focusable by default. You'd have to add a tab index to make that so.

Comment: I tried that, still no changes.